# Retain active steps after adehabitatLT

Tags: r, adehabitathr

I have a dataset of animal GPS locations and I would like to conduct **step-selection functions** analysis.

Firstly, for each step, I have calculated its length and turning angle using the R package *adehabitatLT*; then I have converted the ltraj object to a dataframe with the function *ld*.

Now I would like to keep only *active* steps, i.e. I would like to exclude consecutive GPS fixes below a certain **threshold-distance** (e.g. 100 meters) from each other from the analysis. I am fairly new to this type of spatial selection (I have never had to do it before).

How can I do this in R? Is it correct to delete the dataframe rows where the *dist* value is < than 100m? Does this procedure then preserve the correct values for the respective turning angles?

Thank you very much for your help!

I have tried to do what I wrote but I am not sure it is right from a conceptual point of view.